# In C. Is it wrong to declare int * p = & i;?

Tags: c

```
   int i = 10;
   int *p = &i;
   printf("%d\n", *p);
```

It prints out 10.

However if I write

```
  int i = 10;
  int *p;
  p = &i;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
```

The output is also 10. Is there any difference? The second actually makes more sense to me because it says the value of p is the the address of i, so when dereference p, it gets the value of i. So I am confused what *p = &p is doing at the top?

For another example,

```
int main() {
   int i = 10;
   func (&i);
   return 0;
}
void func (int * p) {
   *p = 15;
}
```

When i is passed to func can I see it as *p = &i ? Since C function passes by value?

Comment: Those are exactly the same. `int *p = &i;` does not actually dereference `p`.

Comment: it's correct. could you explain why the first one makes less sense?

Comment: The first is an initialization, the second an assignment. They both have the same effect.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, I feel the first one means p points to the integer value of &i. so *p will print the value of i's address

Comment: Pointers point to *objects*, not to *values*. `*p` as an expression is equivalent to `i` (as long as `p == &i`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case

```
int *p = &i;
```

The assignment has nothing to do with `*p = &i` and by that i mean, you're not assigning `&i` to the address pointed to by `p`.

Since the type is actually `int*` it will make more sense if you put it this way:

```
int* p = &i;
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, you create `p`as a pointer and assign it the address of `i` in a single operation (initialization).

In the second case, you create `p` as a pointer (it points to random memory address or NULL depending on compiler and optimization) then say on the next line that it should point to `i`.

The end result is exactly the same and it's likely that the compiler will optimize into the exact same code.

NB : pay attention what the star means : `int* p`is similar to `int *p`and means `p` is of type "pointer to int". Once p is defined `*p` dereferences the pointer.

Comment: It's not a dangling pointer. It just has indeterminate value. It becomes a dangling pointer if the object it's pointing to goes out of scope.

Comment: True for the semantics. The effect is however the same : pointing to some undetermined / unowned memory location.

Comment: I rephrased and fixed the previous comment.

Comment: @Bruce not true. dangling pointers have much less chance to trigger memory protection when user tries to dereference them.

Comment: Suspect this may get classified as more semantics: yet with `int* p`, The value of `p` is undefined.  It is not defined to be some pointer to memory, nor `NULL`, simply undefined.  It may have a trap value or a value that does not correspond to memory aside from `NULL`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Both the versions mean the same thing. It's the same thing if you do as follows:

```
// Version 1: initialize and assign a variable in a single command
int i = 10;      // An int
char ch = 'a';   // A char
int *p = &i;     // An int pointer


// Version 2: Use 2 commands for the same effect
int i;      // An int 
i = 10;

char ch;    // A char
ch = 'a';

int *p;     // An int pointer
p = &i;
```

The first version initializes and assigns `i` (or `*p` in your case) in the same command. Whereas the second version initializes the variable in one command, and then assigns it in the next command.

`int *p = &i` is equivalent to writing `int* p = &i` (if you're confused with the former notation). This statement, as you said, assigns the address of `i` to `p`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference. Since you can assign value to a variable when declaring it, both commands assign address of i to p of type pointer to integer (int *).

Declaration:
`int* p = &i; // variable p of type pointer to integer`

Further use:
`p = &i; // after declaring a variable, you do not write its type anymore`

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk character `*` has two roles in C when it comes to pointers:

1. declare pointer variables

The statement `int *p = [some address];`, or equivilently `int* p = [some address];`, is *declaring* a variable called `p` which is a pointer. In this case the `*` character will always appear next to a type, as in `int*`, `float*` or `char*`.

We also use this syntax to pass pointer variables to functions. 
The function below is accepting a pointer-to-integer called `p`, so we declare it with `int*`.

```
void func (int * p) {
   *p = 15;
}
```

2. dereference pointers

This is when we have an existing pointer variable `p` and we want to access the memory address it points to. We can use this to read this data from that address, as in `x = *p;`, or write data to that address, as in `*p = y;`.

Comment: Maybe 3: `*` --> multiplication.

Comment: @chux Well I just feel silly now. ;) Fixed my wording a little.

Comment: @chux: `/*` I'm pretty sure there are still other uses for `*`. `*/`

Comment: @Keith Thompson Can we also count `*=`, `printf("%*d",1,2)` or just plain `'*'`?  Mercifully there are no `*` digraph/trigraph.

Comment: @chux: I was counting that under multiplication. I was also ignoring character constants, string literals, and the contents of comments. Oh, and I forgot about `[*]` notation (N1570 6.7.6.2, 6.7.6.3). And `*` could appear in a header name with an implementation-defined meaning. (Everyone else should probably ignore this.)